# ibus on Gnome Wayland - Is there any workaround to make ibus work in GNOME Wayland session?

Tags: gnome, ibus, wayland, libinput

It's a few months since the Ubuntu 17.10 release which defaults into GNOME Wayland (Xwayland) session. My biggest disappointment is not being able to use ibus input method in a Wayland session on GNOME. Nothing works. No ibus menu in the panel, nothing comes up.

If anyone has been successful in using ibus in GNOME with Wayland, kindly please help.

`ibus-setup` was run, `ibus-daemon` is running. But, ibus is unusable in Gnome shell.

```
:~$ ps aux | grep ibus
gdm        891  0.0  0.1 368424 10184 tty1     Sl   02:36   0:00 ibus-daemon --xim --panel disable
gdm        894  0.0  0.0 286992  7556 tty1     Sl   02:36   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-dconf
gdm        896  0.0  0.3 409564 28124 tty1     Sl   02:36   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-x11 --kill-daemon
gdm        960  0.0  0.0 211140  7404 tty1     Sl   02:36   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-engine-simple
admin20+  9025  0.0  0.1 296024  9364 tty2     Sl   04:27   0:00 ibus-daemon --xim --panel disable
admin20+  9141  0.6  0.1 518268 10800 tty2     Sl   04:31   0:01 ibus-daemon --xim --panel disable
admin20+  9230  0.0  0.0 289116  7460 tty2     Sl   04:33   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-dconf
admin20+  9232  0.0  0.2 367024 22164 tty2     Sl   04:33   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-x11 --kill-daemon
admin20+  9248  0.4  0.1 213384  8252 tty2     Sl   04:33   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-engine-simple
```

Comment: @gunnar-hjalmarsson I haven't had any trouble with Ibus on wayland in fedora, but I haven't tried it in 17.10. Have you seen this problem before?

Comment: No. My other PC is a Desktop running Cinnamon in LMDE. No problems, but here, ibus is listed but not working.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, I failed to figure out new differences in GNOME, that you have to first configure ibus using `ibus-setup`, add `m17n` (in my case) for local languages support (Malayalam, Hindi, Tamil). Then, in **Gnome Settings> Region & Language > Input Sources** Press '+' and add the languages (from **Other** directory for **Indic languages**).

That was enough; now with <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> keyboard shortcut, I can select language input, also the icon appears in the top panel for language selection.